# REST-ful connection utilizing cURL header issues

Tags: php, rest, curl

I've spent hours troubleshooting this utilizing PHP documentation, the API documentation, as well as other posts on stackoverflow, and am finally asking for help.

I am attempting to write an interface utilizing the new pbSmartConnections API: [API Documentation](https://api.pbsyscontrol.com)

I have been having challenges with both fsockopen and cURL, however I seem to be able to get farther in the process utilizing cURL, so that's what I'm presenting here.  Here's the challenge:

Per my understanding of the documentation, I should be passing the ApiKey as part of the header.  When I do this, regardless of the different ways I've attempted to structure the code, I ALWAYS receive the following response:

```
{
    "ErrorCode": 10,
    "Message": "Unauthorized"
}
```

I'm hoping a fellow SO member can see something in my code below (please offer any criticisms and/or suggestions, too!):
(NOTE: The API key below IS valid.  It's connected to an account with nothing of value in it, so feel free to use it in your testing)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.pbsyscontrol.com/v1/Ping");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json", "ApiKey"=>"41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
?>
```

In case you are wondering, while I would like this to work as part of the header, I HAVE tried passing it as a part of the URL as well:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://rest.pbsyscontrol.com/v1/Ping?ApiKey=41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json", "ApiKey"=>"41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
?>
```

Comment: There must be something wrong with the API key or the account. It returns 401 ("401 Unauthorized : The API Key was missing or invalid") even when passing as a query string. I understand the API key is accurate - but is your account valid and active?

Comment: @Mahdi.Montgomery - THANK you for comment.  And yes, I am positive.  I've checked those things so many times it's a bit rediculous.  I've gone so far as to create new API keys and use them, etc.  I've submitted a request to Pitney Bowes, and am awaiting a response.

Comment: try to make it work with `curl` at the command line. Currently it returns `HTTP/1.1 401 Invalid API Key` for the command: `curl -k -H 'ApiKey: 41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071' -i https://rest.pbsyscontrol.com/v1/Ping`

Comment: If https://rest.pbsyscontrol.com/v1/Ping?ApiKey=41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071 then there is a issue with your ApiKey ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally heard back from support, and what they indicated was that I was using the incorrect url (although at this time, it IS the url in their [API Documentation](https://api.pbsyscontrol.com))

The URL in the API documentation was their STAGING, not PRODUCTION.  Amazing what switching the URL to the correct one that they sent in their reply - `rest.api.pbsmartconnections.com` does for the connection.  That one change and everything began working properly.

THANK YOU all who took a look, and to @mvdnes for the recommendations on how to set headers.

Answer (score 2):

The PHP documentation says:

> An array of HTTP header fields to set, in the format `array('Content-type: text/plain', 'Content-length: 100')`

You thus want to use the following line instead of the original:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Accept: application/json", "ApiKey: 41460b3f-8f35-4878-b78d-49ca7f29c071"));
```

This does not however, solve the problem that the ApiKey probably isn't valid.